# Проброс событий C#

Tags: c#, архитектура, события

Есть некоторый класс `Controller`, который является входной точкой в приложение и реализует интерфейс `IController` с набором методов, доступных извне клиентам. Внутри `Controller` состоит из множества компонентов(классов), таких как: `Farmmanager`, `RequestsManager`, `MatrixnnManager` и многих других, которые выполняют разные задачи. Все это хозяйство располагается в `UnityContainer`. При запуске приложения `Controller` создает контейнер и устанавливается взаимодействие между компонентами(`FarmManager` и др)  посредством установления связи между обработчиками одних компонентов и событиями других. Каждый из компонентов внутри имеет подкомпоненты и далее, иерархия может быть глубокой.  Архитектурно получается так, что клиент вызывает какой-то метод `Controller`, а тот в свою очередь вызывает событие, которое уходит компоненту, тот пробрасывает подкомпоненту и далее..  Получается по 5-6 уровней, через которое пробрасывается событие. Архитектурно компоненты никак друг с другом не связаны, кроме как через события и обработчики, но это порождает необходимость сквозных пробросов. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно преобразовать архитектуру так, чтобы несвязность компонентов сохранилась ,однако исчезла бы необходимость реализовывать одно и то же событие во всей иерархии компонента (подкомпонент, подподкомпонент).

Примерно это все выглядит следующим образом: (не стоит искать ошибок в коде, это накиданный пример)

```
 public Class Controller : IController
    {

     public override event Eventhandler NewMessage; 

      public override void AddMessage(T message)
     {
        OnNewMessage();
     }

      public override NodeState GetStateOfNode(int index)
     {
     }

     private void Start()
     {
       var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IFarmManager, FarmManager>(newContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRequestsManager, RequestsManager>(newContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

       NewMessage+= RequestsManager.onNewMessage
     }

    }

  public class RequestsManager: IRequestsManager
  {   
     public override event Eventhandler NewMessage; 

     private QueueProcessDispatcher = new QueueProcessDispatcher();
     public void onNewMessage()
    {
      OnNewMessage();
    }

     public void Start()
    {
      NewMessage+=QueueProcessDispatcher.NewMessage;
    }

  }
```

Comment: P.S. Тоже самое касается и методов.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить пример кода для наглядности.

Comment: А в чём проблема с большим количеством пробросов?

Comment: Проблемы нет, просто при необходимости получать определенное сообщение глубоко внутри приходится делать событие во всех промежуточных интерфейсах.  Нет ли более изящного способа проброса, с уменьшением колстэка?

Comment: Ну можно сделать общий message bus (глобальный объект, у которого любой может опубликовать событии или подписаться на него), но при этом, возможно, внешним слоям нужно будет знать о существовании внутренних, что не очень изящно как-то.

Comment: Да, в том и дело, что нет желания увеличивать связность. Как-то ведь в крупных приложениях решают эту проблему, не все же гоняют туда сюда целые объекты и пулят.  Чистый event-based подход очень приятен, но раздувание интерфейсов и в принципе сложность расширяемости удручает.

Comment: @Sleeeper: ну, а почему бы не сделать так: (1) У вас есть слои, на выходе из каждого нам нужны event'ы с пробросом, т. к. понижение связности. (2) Внутри слоя можно напрямую передавать всё что угодно и куда угодно. (3) Если у вас 6 слоёв — ну да, 6 ивентов в стеке. Это очень мало, кстати. (3а) Если у вас 100 слоёв — что-то не так с архитектурой, укрупняйте.

Comment: Ну у меня до 6-7 слоев, вряд ли будет еще.  Спасибо Вам за разъяснение!!!

Comment: P.S. остается только небольшой осадок от того, что как-то это не совсем правильно, что ли, хоть и допустимо при такой вложенности...